# Hi, I'm struggling with very basic python code. I face an error saying TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

```
class Yookyung:
    def __init__(self, feeling, weight):
        self.feeling = feeling
        self.weight = weight
        
    def speak(self):
        print("Iam so "+ self.feeling+ "because I am"+ self.weight+ "kg now.")
```

```
SadYookyung = Yookyung("sad", 57)
```

```
SadYookyung.speak()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2639abd46a5d> in <module>
----> 1 SadYookyung.speak()

<ipython-input-1-a640ca3e899e> in speak(self)
      5 
      6     def speak(self):
----> 7         print("Iam so "+ self.feeling+ "because I am"+ self.weight+ "kg now.")

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Comment: You are trying to concat a string, which is `"Iam so "+ self.feeling+ "because I am"` to an integer `self.weight`. Python does not allow that. Just convert self.weight to a string like `str(self.weight)` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way,

```
def speak(self):
    print(f"Iam so {self.feeling} because I am {self.weight}kg now.")
```

> Note: Make sure to use python latest version because in some lower
> versions this type of formatting is not supported.

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as an accepted answer so that it will be helpful for others to grasp :)

Comment: As long as you are using a *supported* version of Python (3.6 or later), you'll be fine. (Even 3.6 is old enough to be going out of support at the end of the year. Python 3.9 is the most current version.)

Answer (score 0):

Try f string:

```
def speak(self):
    print(f"I am so {self.feeling} because I am {self.weight} kg now.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `+` when used between two strings means concatenation, between two numbers means a sum, so when you mix those types, the interpreter gets confused.

Python provides a very easy way to format strings so you don't have to worry about data types and concatenation:

```
name = 'Guest'
greet = 'Hello'
print(f'{greet} {name}')

# or

print('{} {}'.format(greet, name))
```